# How to connect one css with multiable html pages

Tags: html, css

So I new to html and want to make a website with 2 pages a home page and a contact page.
and I just want to know how do you use the same Style.css file for then 1 page?

Do just write in the Style.css:
***#Home body;

#Contact body;***

Comment: Duplicate the CSS file to each folder and listed it in the `head` in the index file?

Comment: Just write all CSS rules in a single file and `link` that file in both the HTML pages. To organise your CSS rules you have few options — elements which are similar in style can be given `class` attribute and you can style all those elements with single class selector. However I'll suggest to keep some common CSS in a single file to link with multiple pages and make page specific CSS files separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of explaining, i have created 2 divs in one page. But you can create homepage and put "homepage" div in it and "contact" div on another page

```css
.homepage {
    /* All css needed for homepage will come here */
}

.contact {
    /* All css needed for contact will come here */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="homepage">
        page 1 content
    </div>

    <div class="contact">
        contact content
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```